# How to integrate $\int_{1.96}^{\infty}e^{-\frac {x^2} {2}}\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I can't integrate it using the methods I know.

Comment: Famously, there is no closed form in terms of elementary functions for the indefinite integral of $e^{-ax^2}$. So this has to be done numerically, e.g., http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+e%5E%28-x%5E2%2F2%29+dx%2C+x%3D1.96..infty

Comment: The primitive of this function cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. But $1.96$ happens to be (an approximation of) a value well known to anybody interested in the so called error function or, equivalently, in gaussian distributions... Thus the integral in the title is (approximately) $\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot0.025$. (Rather amazingly (to me), googling 1.96 produces [this quite relevant page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1.96).)

Comment: By the way, if ever one question could be seen as "lacking context", this one definitely can.

Answer (score 3):

If you remember the z-scores of a standard normal distribution, $\int_{1.96}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}=1-N(1.96)\approx0.025$, where $N(.)$ is the CDF of a standard normal distribution.

So the answer is approximately $0.025\times \sqrt{2\pi}\approx0.025*2.5=0.0625$.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the antiderivative first $$\int e^{-c x^2}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{2 \sqrt{c}}~~\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{c} x\right)$$ where appears the error function. Now, for the integral $$\int_b^\infty e^{-c x^2}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{2 \sqrt{c}}\Big(1-\text{erf}\left(b \sqrt{c}\right)\Big)$$ If you go to the Wikipedia page, you will find a series of more or less accurate numerical approximations of the error function. One which is quite simple is $$\text{erf(x)}\approx \text{sgn}(x)\sqrt{1-e^{-\frac{x^2 \left(a x^2+\frac{4}{\pi }\right)}{a x^2+1}}}$$ where $$a=\frac{8 (\pi -3)}{3 (4-\pi ) \pi }\approx 0.140012$$ Applied to your case $c=\frac12$, $b=1.96$, the above formula gives $\approx 0.06225$ while the exact value would be $\approx 0.06266$ which is not too bad for practical purposes.

Using $a=0.148009$ would give a better approximation ($\approx 0.06257$).

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea in solving it but not sure if it is useful or no!

$\begin{array}{l}
u = \frac{{{x^2}}}{2} \Rightarrow S = \int\limits_{1.96}^\infty  {{e^{ - u}}\frac{1}{{\sqrt u }}} du\\
t = u - 1.96 \Rightarrow S = \int\limits_0^\infty  {{e^{ - t}}\frac{{{e^{ - 1.96}}}}{{\sqrt {t + 1.96} }}} dt
\end{array}$

Then use Laplace transform definition to find the integral.

Comment: Please read on my lips: " The primitive of this function cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions."